Formula to compare two date fields in SharePoint Lists
I have two date fields, not time stamp, in SharePoint that I want to display an error if one date is less than or equal to the other date field.
I'm not looking to calculate anything, just a simple error to look at the two fields.   
I thought the formula was:
=[Date ISL Reported]<=[Date Reported to Hayden] 


Where are you adding this formula? Are you getting any error while adding formula OR formula is not working as expected?

Your formula looks good to me. But, make sure to use this formula in List validation settings instead of Column validation settings.
If you want validation like Date ISL Reported should be less than or equal to Date Reported to Hayden, use formula like this:
=[Date ISL Reported]<=[Date Reported to Hayden]


Output:

You can find the detailed steps to add list validation formula in my answer at: List validation if then syntax
Note:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).
Use correct display name of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
Wrap column names inside [] if your column name has space in it. For example: [My Column Name].

